# filename.gz installation on AIX

Tags: software-installation, tar, aix, gzip

I use

```
sudo tar xvzf forwarder.tar -C /opt/
```

on Linux and this works perfectly then I proceed with a

```
. /splunk start
```

to install a forwarder file.

While in AIX, its forwarder is in `.gz` format and I tried using

```
gzip -d filename.gz
```

And it just decompresses the `gz` file. Tried also using

```
sudo tar -xvf -C "/directory/path/" "/home/forwarder.gz"
```

and its not working too. Tried using `.tar` also on the command above but to no avail, got no result. How to install on AIX?

Comment: "not working" is not a diagnose. If you will not provide any more details about "what is not working", you will probably not get any better answer.

Comment: You are so close. Why didn't you try gzip -d followed by tar?

Comment: @Jakuje the sudo tar -xvf -C "/directory/path" "/home/forwarder.gz" command that I used was giving an error that goes like tar: -C: directory or file path not found. Can't post the exact error today but will post it by Friday. Can't test it today because I don't have an access to the server now and and Im basically googling unix commands on AIX but can't make it work as I've said.

Comment: @JeffSchaller followed by tar like? Can you please explain it further?

Comment: @Lloyd: tar is pretty picky about the order of the options and arguments, it always expects after -f option the filename, hence it failed in your example above as you put "-C" there. And for your understanding, on linux tar is usually linked to commonly used (de-)compressors like gzip, bzip2, lzma, xz etc.pp. But originally tar itself is only a simple archiver without compression support. The AIX tar is one without integrated support for external (de-)compressors, so you need to do things manually one after the other, first gunzip and then tar, like meuh or Jeff described already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though we cannot be sure of what your file contains,
as @JeffSchaller suggested, try piping the output of gzip into tar as follows:

```
gzip -d <filename.gz | 
sudo tar -xvf - -C "/directory/path/"
```

If this doesnt provide your wanted file, then use the `file` command on the data to see what type it is. Eg: `file filename.gz`, and if it is a compressed file then `gzip -d <filename.gz | file -`.

Comment: One could use `gzip -d <filename.gz | tar -tvf -` to see what the tarball contains. It should also be mentioned that sudo is not contained in a default installation, so it should be omitted in my opinion and a hint about necessary root permissions added instead :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the correct gzip flags are **"-dc"** as the -c writes to stdout and then the pipe can process it the rest of the way.
I frequently use:

```
gzip -dc something.tar.gz | tar -xf -
```

to unpack an a gzipped archive. And for bz2, xz, etc.. the commands are similiar:

```
bzip2 -dc something.tar.bz2 | tar xf -
xz -dc something.tar.xz | tar xf -
```

And if you are worried that a .tgz file is not going to be accepted by gzip use:

```
cat something.tgz | gzip -dc - | tar xf -
```

p.s. these also ALL work on Linux (where I have tried them at least)